# Move the code from Qt to AndroidSDK

Tags: android, c++, qt

I got used with programming in Nokia's QtSDK (C++) and published a few simple apps in the Nokia's Store. I want to move to Android platform now but am quite confused how to do it in a simple and natural way.

I have a nice working (desktop) app which would perfectly fit for tablet devices. It was written in C++. I have difficulties in understanding how to move that code to Android platform and publish the app in Google's Play Store.

The question is: can it be compiled in QtCreator and would fulfill publish requirements or should it be moved to AndroidSDK? I want to avoid Necessitas plugin.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Qt 4 or Qt 5?

Answer (score 0):

Qt targets Android, so you don't need to abandon Qt at all. Simply download Qt for Android, add it to available Qt versions and Qt kits in Qt Creator, and follow the [documentation](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/android-support.html) to tweak your project to run on Android !